# ¿Alguien sabe cual es la causa del error de sintaxis?

Tags: python

```
class Punto2D():
    """Representacion de punto en 2 dimenciones"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        return x

    def get_y(self):
        return y

    def radio_polar(self):
        return math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)

    def angulo_polar(self):
        return math.atan2(x / y)

    def dist_euclidiana(self, Punto2D other):
        dx = self.x - other.get_x()
        dy = self.y - other.get_y()
        return math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
```

El error en concreto es:

> def angulo_polar(self):
>          ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hola Kevin, bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://stackoverflow.com/help) para formular mejores preguntas, y obtener respuestas útiles para ti y los demás; por el momento, tu pregunta está incompleta pues no sabemos qué error específico te presenta, por lo que no podemos ayudarte tan bien, si todo estaría completo.

Comment: Si hay un error deberías indicar el mensaje y en que línea, por lo pronto lo único que logro identificar es `math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)` que le falta el paréntesis final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores, además del que ocasiona el error de sintaxis:

- En el método `radio_polar` te falta cerrar un paréntesis, debería ser

  ```
  return math.sqrt((self.x * self.x) + (self.y * self.y))
  ```

  Este es el error que obtienes. Ante estos errores te recomiendo mirar la línea anterior a la marcada por el error, dado que suele ser común que la causa sea la falta del cierre de un parétesis, llave, etc en esa línea. Cabe mencionar que si se usa IDLE como IDE este tipo de errores no son muy autoexplicativos, simplemente aparece un popup de error avisando que existe un error de sintaxis sin más información, pero si te fijas aparece el inicio de la línea (en tu caso el `def`) subrayado indicando la línea del error.
- En `dist_euclidiana` la definición es incorrecta, debería ser:

  ```
  def dist_euclidiana(self, other):
  ```

  Sobra el nombre de la clase delante del parámetro, esto ocasiona otro error de sintaxis.
- En tus métodos debes anteponer `self` a los nombres de los atributos de instancia como haces correctamente en `dist_euclidiana`.
- Estas calculando mal el ángulo polar, debe ser `math.atan2(y, x)`. `math.atan2` recibe dos valores (`y`, `x`) y calcula el valor de `atan(y/x)`. En tu código solo le pasas un valor (`x / y`) y además inviertes el orden de las coordenadas.

Por otro lado, si con `get_x` y `get_y` te limitas a retornar el valor del atributo, deberías prescindir de ambos métodos y simplemente aceder directamente a los atributos de la instancia. Si deseas validar los parámetros (por ejemplo, aceptar solo enteros), considera usar properties, que es la manera más "pythónica" de definir lo que se conocen como setters y getters en otros lenguajes.

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
import math


class Punto2D:
    """Representacion de punto en 2 dimenciones"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int): 
            raise ValueError("x debe ser un entero")
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError("y debe ser un entero")
        self._y = value

    def radio_polar(self):
        return math.sqrt((self._x * self._x) + (self._y * self._y))

    def angulo_polar(self):
        return math.atan2(self._y, self._x)

    def dist_euclidiana(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Punto2D):
            raise ValueError("El parámetro <other> debe ser una instancia de Punto2D")

        dx = self.x - other.x
        dy = self.y - other.y
        return math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
>>> A = Punto2D(2, 6)
>>> B = Punto2D(1, 2)
>>> A.radio_polar()
6.324555320336759
>>> A.angulo_polar()
1.2490457723982544
>>> A.dist_euclidiana(B)
4.123105625617661
>>> A.x
2
>>> A.y
6
>>> B.x
1
>>> B.y
2
```

> **Nota:** En este caso, el setter solo valida enteros, cualquier otra instancia pasada al inicializar o al asignar un valor a los atributos `x` e `y` posteriormente ocasionará una exepción (`ValueError`). Si por ejemplo quisieras permitir también `float` solo tendrías que hacer  `if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):`